# Calculating output column names from dplyr mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

Is there a way to extract the names of the output columns from dplyr mutate?

I have a function that uses `dplyr::mutate()` and I'd like to be able to extract the names of the columns that were used and/or new, without using `transmute()`.

##### Example pseudo function

```
my_function <- function(.data, ...){
  out <- mutate(.data, ...)
  
  ### Pseudo code to calculate output column names
  # out_names <- "code to calculate the used and new col names"
  
  out_names
}
```

##### Example user input

```
library(dplyr)
my_function(iris, Sepal.Length = as.integer(Sepal.Length),
               across(all_of("Sepal.Width"), \(x) x * 100),
               Petal.Width = Petal.Length,
               new_column = 42)
```

##### Desired output

```
c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Width", "new_column")
```

The reason for this is I have custom functions that call `mutate()` quite often and I need to use those output names for further transformations.

Any help and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: one option could be using capturing the code as text, running a regex on it, then running eval(parse()) on it

Comment: That's an interesting though I imagine quite involved idea. Would you happen to have any example code?

Comment: I'll write something up!

Comment: though `fortunes::fortune(106)` is relevant here

Comment: I had a somewhat similar question, asking about python's pandas. The solution there was to `pop()` the used ones. Something similar could work here

Comment: are you wanting the function to run the code as well, or just get the column names?

Comment: @Mark I need a solution that only evaluates the expressions once (in the first mutate call) ideally. It should also be able to work with basically any expression that `mutate()` can accept, including expressions involving `pick()` and `across()`.

Comment: @Mark Agree with the quote, I try to avoid using eval/parse where possible lol.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to capture the call and 1) extract the named transformations. 2) `across()` calls, are passed to `tidyselect::eval_select()` so that the names of variables that are "tidyselected" can be extracted.

```
my_function <- function(.data, ...) {
  fcall <- match.call()
  res <- as.list(fcall)[3:length(fcall)]
  named_vars <- names(res)[names(res) != ""]
  across_vars <- unlist(lapply(res[names(res) == ""], \(x) names(tidyselect::eval_select(x[[2]], .data))))
  out_names <- unique(unname(c(named_vars, across_vars)))
  
  # rest of your function
  out <- mutate(.data, ...)
  out_names[!out_names %in% names(formals(dplyr:::mutate.data.frame))
}

my_function(iris,
          Sepal.Length = as.integer(Sepal.Length),
          across(all_of("Sepal.Width"), \(x) x * 100),
          Petal.Width = Petal.Length,
          new_column = 42)

[1] "Sepal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "new_column"   "Sepal.Width"
```

Comment: Thanks Ritchie, this is great! It works nicely for `across()` calls but not for `pick()` calls and unnamed columns. For example `my_function(iris, rowSums(pick(1:2)))` produces an error.

Comment: I realise though that I didn't include that in my original question and your solution does work for the example I gave so that one's on me.

Answer (score 1):

If computing the custom mutate is not too expensive and you can afford to do it twice, then I would simply change to `transmute` and pull the columns names. This makes it super easy to grab the names of all the columns that were used in the custom function.

```r
library(tidyverse)

my_function <- function(.data, ...){
  out <- mutate(.data, ...)
  out_temp <- transmute(.data, ...)
  
  colnames(out_temp)
}

my_function(iris, Sepal.Length = as.integer(Sepal.Length),
               across(all_of("Sepal.Width"), \(x) x * 100),
               Petal.Width = Petal.Length,
               new_column = 42)
#> [1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Width"  "new_column"
```

As noted in your comments, this method also works with unnamed functions:

```r
my_function(iris, rowSums(pick(1:2)))
#> [1] "rowSums(pick(1:2))"
```

Of course if you only need the column names and not to actually evaluate the mutate, then you can drop the original mutate and only use transmute.

Comment: Thanks AndS, this is a fine solution and one I have used before. The main issue with this method other than the fact that it can be expensive is that side effects from custom expressions are also evaluated twice.

Comment: You could replace '.data' in the 2nd line of the function with slice(ungroup(.data), n = 1) which makes it less expensive but fails for some random functions which might require vector arguments of length > 1